# Indicate weekdays vs weekend

Tags: dates, readability

I have blocks representing weeks, and above each week the dates for the whole week are displayed, i.e.

```
 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
 ____________________
|                    |

 18 19 20 21 22 23 24
 ____________________
|                    |
```

For clarity, is there any common way to indicate which days are weekdays and which are weekend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest notation I've seen is to simply bold them. Another option is to give them a slightly different background color. It really depends on how you are using other elements to indicate events on days. It often helps to include in the top row the list of days so that it is clear whether you are formatting using S M T W R F S or M T W R F S S for your days.